# Computing $\int_0^1dx\:I_0(\alpha \sqrt{1-x})e^{\beta x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, bessel-functions

Let $\alpha,\:\beta$ be positive constants and $I_0(x)$ the modified Bessel function. Any idea about how to calculate the following integral ?

$$
\begin{equation}
f(\alpha,\beta)=\int_0^1dx\:I_0(\alpha \sqrt{1-x})\:e^{\beta x}.
\end{equation}
$$

I've tried expanding the exponential but then the coefficients are given by some $_p F_q$ function whose summation is perhaps more difficult than the original problem.

Comment: I found $$
\frac{{e^\beta  }}{\beta }\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{P(n + 1,\beta )}}{{n!}}\left( {\frac{\alpha }{{2\sqrt \beta  }}} \right)^{2n} } 
$$ where $P$ is the normalised lower incomplete gamma function. Is this reasonable? Note that $$
P(n + 1,\beta ) = 1 - e^{ - \beta } \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\frac{{\beta ^k }}{{k!}}} .
$$

Comment: @Gary the fraction of the regularized gamma function and factorial reminds me of the [Marcum Q function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcum_Q-function). In fact, the powers of the function and exponential coefficient match the definition of the function.

Comment: @TymaGaidash Thanks. I added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
\begin{align*}
 \int_0^1 {I_0 (\alpha \sqrt {1 - x} )e^{\beta x} dx}  & = 2e^\beta  \int_0^1 {I_0 (\alpha t)e^{ - \beta t^2 } tdt} \\ & = 2e^\beta  \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n!^2 }}\left( {\frac{\alpha }{2}} \right)^{2n} \int_0^1 {e^{ - \beta t^2 } t^{2n + 1} dt} } \\ & = \frac{{e^\beta  }}{\beta }\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{P(n + 1,\beta )}}{{n!}}\left( {\frac{\alpha }{{2\sqrt \beta  }}} \right)^{2n} } ,
\end{align*}
where $P$ is the normalised lower incomplete gamma function. It may be written in terms of the Marcum $Q$-function as
$$
\frac{1}{\beta }\exp \left( {\frac{{\alpha ^2 }}{{4\beta }} + \beta } \right)\left( {1 - Q_1 \!\left( {\frac{\alpha }{{\sqrt {2\beta } }},\sqrt {2\beta } } \right)} \right).
$$

Comment: Thank you ! Just to make sure, the normalization amounts to divide by $\Gamma(n+1)$, right ? I.e., $P(n+1,\beta)=\Gamma(n+1)^{-1}\cdot \gamma(n+1,\beta)=\Gamma(n+1)^{-1} \int_0^\beta \mathrm{d}t\: t^n e^{-t}$.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @Gary See the CDF of the [Non-central chi squared distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution). The answer maybe can be simplified.

Answer (score 2):

Note change variables $y=\alpha\sqrt{1-x}$ to get
$$
f(\alpha,\beta) = \frac{2e^\beta}{\alpha^2}\int_0^\alpha 
I_0(y) \exp\left(\frac{-\beta}{\alpha^2}y^2\right)y\;dy
$$
So evaluating this for all $\alpha,\beta$ means finding the **indefinite integral**
$$
\int I_0(y) e^{-cy^2}y\;dy
$$

This is not listed in

*Gradshteyn, I. S.; Ryzhik, I. M.; Zwillinger, Daniel (ed.); Moll, Victor (ed.)*, [**Table of integrals, series, and products. Translated from the Russian. Translation edited and with a preface by Victor Moll and Daniel Zwillinger**](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/book/9780123849335), Amsterdam: Elsevier/Academic Press (ISBN 978-0-12-384933-5/hbk; 978-0-12-384934-2/ebook). xlv, 1133 p. (2015). [ZBL1300.65001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1300.65001).

---

On the other hand, there is a **definite** integral:
$$
\int_0^\infty x e^{-cx^2} I_0(x)\;dx = \frac{e^{1/(4c)}}{2c},\quad c>0
$$
which becomes
$$
\int_{-\infty}^1 e^{\beta x}I_0(\alpha\sqrt{1-x}) =
\frac{\exp\left(\beta - \frac{\alpha^2}{4\beta}\right)}{\beta}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$I_0(\alpha \sqrt{1-x})=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{ \alpha ^{2 n} }{4^n(n!)^2}(x-1)^n$$

$$\int (x-1)^n e^{\beta x}\,dx=e^\beta\int y^n e^{\beta y} \,dy=\frac {e^\beta }{\beta^{n+1} }\int t^n \,e^t\,dt$$ Now, the incomplete gamma function.

Answer (score 1):

It seems a closed form exists using the following definition from [Wikipedia of the Marcum Q function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcum_Q-function) used in many distributions. It is a bit obscure, but works. You will find the rest of the needed information to understand this result in the link:

> $$\mathrm{Q_m(a,b)=1-e^{-\frac{a^2}2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{a^2}{2}\right)^n\frac{P\left(m+n,\frac{b^2}2\right)}{n!}}$$

This needs to be equal to @Gary’s solution

$$\mathrm{A\,Q_x(y,z)+B=\frac{e^β}β\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{P(n+1,β)}{n!}\left(\frac{α}{2\sqrtβ}\right)^{2n}}$$